# How web server send data to web browser over network?

Tags: sockets, networking, webserver

I want to know how web server can reach to client which is behind the router?
When i tried connect to ip of my friend i didn't success (we are not in local network), and when web server try to send data over network to him it success. How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web server does not initiate the connection.  Rather, the client initiates a connection to the web server.  The router adjusts the client's connection initiation on the way to the internet, and when the web server sends the response to the router across the connection, the router already knows about the connection and knows how to forward the data to the client.

If you are not behind a router, your friend should be able to initiate a TCP connection to your machine, even though you can't initiate one to him.  If you are both behind routers, though, that won't work.

Comment: Thank you, that's it. :) When i try open socket with my application (written in c) to some web server the firewall alarm, and when chrome/firefox open socket to web server firewall doesn't allarm, why ?

Comment: @Igor Thanks.  Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark if it was useful.

Comment: It requires 15 reputation, but i dont have it.

Comment: Weird.  You should be able to accept the answer to your own question wiithout any rep.  I think you need 15 rep to upvote, though.